# Running robotframework tests simultaneously

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way to run all my test cases simultaneously? if so could you please post an example of how to do it?
Regards,
Meir

Comment: there is no embedded solution to run all your tests in parallel in Robot Framework. Some people implement ways to run sub-parts of their portfolio and then merge the reports in a single one using rebot tool though. Could you elaborate a bit on what you intend to to? How could you run *all* your test at once?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built-in to robot to run tests in parallel. If your tests are spread across multiple suites you can write a script that runs them all at the same time, and then you can use [rebot](https://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#rebot) to combine all of the output.xml files into a single report.

There is an open source program that might do what you want. The project is named "pabot" and can be found  here: https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot