# how to execute test case simultaneously in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have written test case and kept in one folder how to execute all test case one by one continue.
Test case are like
Test case 1: demo.text
Test case 2: d.text

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19345467/7432, but SO won't let me close this as a duplicate, since the other question doesn't have an accepted or upvoted answer. If you want to answer this, please add your answer to the original question and/or upvote the answers that are already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a common Tag to all your testcases and then you can run you testcase by using that Tag. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry i am new , how can you explain it(common tag means)  thanks

Comment: @rahul U can add Tags section while writing your Testcases; in [Tags] section provide same tags to all your testcases and run your testcases by using "pybot -i <Tag name> testSuite"

Comment: Thanks @erpm31, its working but there is error: [error] opening output file 'C:/output.xml' failed permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize your test cases. Use Parallel pybot: 
https://github.com/workshare/parallel_pybot/

or the one I prefer: Pabot:

https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot/  pabot

Once you download pabot, just put demo.txt and d.txt in a folder named 'sample_folder' and then just run 'pabot sample_foler'. Good luck!

Comment: error: no test case to execute, i have downloaded pabot i kept test case in sample_folder (test case i wrote in seperate and keyword and variable in seperate  and i imported this in test case )     example:***Settings ***
Resource   Resourced.txt
*** Test Cases ***
valid Login
   Open Browser and Search

Comment: and in Resourced.txt i have written keyword and variable

Comment: you have to create a directory, then put your .txt file in that directory. Then call, "pabot (name of directory which has your robot .txt file)".  good luck!

Comment: Testcases are passed but output is showing error:   robot.errors:Data Errors opening c:\output.xml error permission denied

Comment: Np. Try doing the command using 'sudo'. Also could you please check 'answered correctly' for my answer? Thank you

Comment: thanks,i checked your answer correctly and applied correctly its working

Comment: thanks,i checked your answer correctly and applied correctly its working         but  robot.errors:Data Errors opening c:\output.xml error permission denied                                     its firefox browser error or another error